# Which all sects have the concept of Śaraṇāgati and/or Prapatti or any equivalent?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, moksha, bhakti, sects

Śaraṇāgati (शरणागति) and Prapatti (प्रपत्ति) - *nyāsa vidyā*, are two/three such practises to attain Moksha with least possible effort, which I have encountered in reference to Śrī-Vaiṣṇavism or the larger Vaiṣṇavism Saṃpradāya's jargon exclusively.

Which all other sects also have such practises by same name, or other similar equivalents with different names, for 'complete unequivocal surrender' unto their respective tutelary deity (Iṣṭa) to gain Moksha? And what's procedure?

Or this is limited to only Vaiṣṇava sect exclusively?